# What are the steps to create or generate an Excel sheet in OpenERP?

Tags: python, odoo

I need to know, what are the steps to generate an Excel sheet in OpenERP?

Or put it this way, I want to generate an Excel sheet for data that I have retrieved from different tables through queries with a function that I call from a button on wizard. Now I want when I click on the button an Excel sheet should be generated.

I have installed OpenOffice, the problem is I don't know how to create that sheet and put data on it. Please will you tell me the steps?

Comment: Thanks for editing and making it a complete question , Anyway i solved my problem with XlsxWriter and passthrough SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily with python library called XlsxWriter. Just download it and add in openerp Server, look for XlsxWriter Documentation , plus there are also other python libraries for generating Xlsx reports.

Comment: Thanks , that's what exactly i did. anyway thanks for your answer